# Terraform: How to automate pulling and running docker images from Azure Container Registry

Tags: docker-image, terraform-provider-azure, azure-container-registry

I want to automate the process of pulling docker images from Azure container Registry to the Azure VM. I have already done the following:

1. Created an Azure container Registry.
2. Setup username and password in the Azure Container Registry.
3. Pushed the image from my local machine to the Container Registry.

I have setup up terraform code to automate the build out of Azure VM. I also want to include the docker pull and docker run commands so that those tasks are automated. Below are the commands I would like to automate into terraform:

```
sudo docker login --username xxx --password xxx xxx.azurecr.io
sudo docker pull xxx.azurecr.io/xx/xxx
sudo docker run --network=host xxx.azurecr.io/xxx/xxx
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you folks!

Answer (score 1):

As I know, if you want to execute the Docker CLI command in the VM, you should install the Docker engine first.

In addition, if you want to run the Docker CLI commands in the VM automated after creating the VM through Terraform, You can use [VM extension in Terraform](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/virtual_machine_extension.html). Write a shell script with the commands and then run it in the VM extension. Here is the example that [Using Terraform with Azure VM Extensions](https://jackstromberg.com/2018/11/using-terraform-with-azure-vm-extensions/).

Comment: Charles, Thank you! Azure Image comes pre-loaded with Docker. I will use Azure VM extensions and try to get the Docker command automated.

Comment: That's great. If no more question and it's helpful you can accept it as the answer.

Comment: @samcoug Any more question?

Comment: I have no move questions for now. Thank you so much Charles.

Comment: @samcoug If the answer works to you. Then you can accept it as the answer.

Comment: @CharlesXu Can you please ellaborate how to do this? As I am also new to this. I need to pull a docker image from ACR and deploy the same on a VM using Terraform but have not found any solutions for the same yet.